# Explanation of setTitle method in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `FragmentActivity` which has a `ViewPager` and my question is:
Where does `setTitle(int index)` method come from?

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    };
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float posOffset, int a) {{

    };
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
        String title = Integer.toString(pos);
        setTitle(title); // where are you coming from?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from the surrounding (not listed) `FragmentActivity`. The `FragmentActivity` inherits it from `Activity`. See the API-Documentation of [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) and [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(int)) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The method comes from activity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)